# Will using short attribute names in JSON reduce bandwidth used in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, json, optimization, compression, firebase

Does [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com) GZIP or do any other kind of compression/optimization before sending in either direction? I can't find any mention of this happening, and the REST API clearly doesn't do this, but for all I know there is some magic happening in client-side Firebase JS that compresses/decompresses when sending/receiving.

Some of the attribute names I use are pretty long, to make my code more readable, and I have large quantities of otherwise-small objects.

Gzipping all of the JSON in my Firebase reduces its size by 85%, though there are also a lot of large strings which probably account for plenty of this compression. I don't actually need very granular access to the data in my app, so now that I think of it I'm tempted to do some compression myself ([JavaScript implementation of Gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294297/javascript-implementation-of-gzip)) on stringified JSON.

Related question: [Is it worth the effort to try to reduce JSON size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160941/is-it-worth-the-effort-to-try-to-reduce-json-size), which references [JSONH](https://github.com/WebReflection/JSONH) which looks interesting.

Comment: For Firebase's REST API, `curl -I` gives me `405 Method Not Allowed`, but doing `curl -v` I can see the headers and it appears that it is not compressed. However, I still don't know what's going on inside the client-side Firebase JS - I believe it's using web sockets and nothing is showing up in the Chrome dev tools network tab.

Comment: Nope, still not compressed. But anything that I do with `curl` over the REST API is irrelevant to what Firebase is actually doing in my application, which I believe uses different methods to access and update that date.

Comment: Firebase doesn't do any compression on its own in the JS library. If you don't need granular access, I recommend compressing/uncompressing the data on your own.

Comment: It would be great if there were a way to enable compression. JSON can be very compressible.